# Colección de datos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, matriz, programacion-asincrona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me solicitaron que trabaja html, realizando una tabla en javacript, pues con información de una matriz con información de los usuarios, pero ahora que he realizado, tengo que hacer que en el la web aparezca la misma tabla de datos solo realizado con un for, para poder optimizar el codigo y reducir las lineas de codigo realizando lo mismo, pero tecnicamente con lo mismo que ya he realizado

```js
 export const user = [
    {
      id: 143,
      name: `sofia Gutierrez`,
      email: `SoGui@gmail.com`,
    },
    {
      id: 123,
      name: `Jose Hernandez`,
      email: `jhe@gmail.com`,
    },
    {
      id: 65,
      name: `Carla Flores`,
      email: `CarlaFl@gmail.com`,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: `Juan Gonzales`,
      email: `Juan@gmail.com`,
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      name: `Carlos Ordoñez`,
      email: `carlos@gmail.com`,
    },
    
   ]


import {user} from "./data.js"

let root = document.getElementById("root");

let title = `<h1 style="color:red;">` + `LISTADO DE USUARIOS` +  `</h1>`;


let table = `<table border="1">` + 
           `<tr>` +
              `<td>` + `NAMES` + `</td>` +
              `<td>` +  `ID`  + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + `EMAIL` + `</td>` +     
           `</tr>` +
           `<tr>` +
              `<td>` + user[0].name  + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[0].id    + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[0].email + `</td>`  +     
           `</tr>` +
           `<tr>` +
              `<td>` + user[1].name  + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[1].id    + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[1].email + `</td>` +     
           `</tr>` +
           `<tr>` +
              `<td>` + user[2].name   + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[2].id     + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[2].email  + `</td>` +     
           `</tr>` +
           `<tr>` +
              `<td>` + user[3].name   + '</td>' +
              `<td>` + user[3].id     + '</td>' +
              `<td>` + user[3].email  + '</td>' +     
           `</tr>` +

           `<tr>` +
              `<td>` + user[4].name   + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[4].id     + `</td>` +
              `<td>` + user[4].email  + `</td>` +     
           `</tr>` +
           
        `</table>`;


   root.innerHTML = title + table;[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
   
   
 [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Qué tal?

Podría seguir lo siguiente donde renderice según su matriz , usando usando map junto con template strings + placeholders `${}` ECMAScript 6 (ES6)

1. **Map:** *Permite iterar sobre un arreglo y modificar sus elementos utilizando una función callback, donde esta ejecutará cada uno de
   los elementos del arreglo*
2. **Template Strings:** *Permite utilizar cualquier expresión válida de JavaScript (`table`, `headers` en este caso) dentro de una cadena y obtener
   como resultado
   la cadena completa.*

Ya que su matriz tiene la misma estructura solo tome 2 índices para el ejemplo

```
const user = [
  {
    id: 143,
    name: 'sofia Gutierrez',
    email: 'SoGui@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Jose Hernandez',
    email: 'jhe@gmail.com'
  },
 ]

const headers = ['NAMES', 'ID', 'EMAIL']
const title = `<h1 style="color:red;">LISTADO DE USUARIOS </h1>`; //Podría ser caption
const table = 
  `<table border="1" cellpadding = "5" cellspacing = "5">
    <tr>
    ${headers.map(names => `<td>${names}</td>`)}
  </tr>
    ${user.map(({name,id,email}) =>
      (
        `
      <tr>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${id}</td>
        <td>${email}</td>
      </tr>
        `
      )
    )}                             
  </table>`
  
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = title + table;
```

De esta manera esta iterando cada índice/par clave-valor de su matriz desestructurándolos en el camino para interpolarlos en los `td`.

-En cuanto a su diseño puedo jugar con esto y modificar el estilo de su tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda